# convert HTML entities

Tags: xml, xls

I have xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<field>
<ID><![CDATA[&lt;table style=&quot;width: 700px;&quot; align=&quot;left&quot; border=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&lt;tbody&gt;&lt;]]></ID>
</field>
```

I want to convert this xml by xsl to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<field>
<ID><![CDATA[<table style="width: 700px;" align="left" border="0"><tbody><]]></ID>
</field>
```

My xsl file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I convert these tags html tags to <>" ?
Regards.

Comment: Are you using php?

Comment: @mayersdesign He has XSL, PHP is unnecessary and restrictive.

Comment: No, I can't do it with PHP.
I want do this only by xls, because my "shop downloader" doesn't accept php language.